# C functions in round brackets

Tags: c, function, printf, language-lawyer, comma-operator

I just noticed that it's possible in C to run functions by placing them in round brackets separated by commas. I wonder whether it is equivalent to just running them normally (without outside round brackets, separated by semicolons) and where this syntax or behavior originates from (was this added as a feature, does this have a special name, are there wanted side-effects, is this actually used etc.). It's quite intriguing how I write this sequence thousands of time a day for many years as part of function calls but I can't remember having seen this standalone even once.

example.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (printf("Hello "), printf("World!\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for lending your knowledge, Moritz

Comment: That's the [comma operator (C11 6.5.17)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.17) at work. You really don't want to use it (like that).

Comment: "Round brackets" are better known as parentheses.  They're unnecessary in your example.  The relevant item is the comma, which creates a comma expression.  You don't need to wrap it in parentheses.  But there's no reason to use a comma expression in this example.  You're better off using individual statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where this syntax or behavior originates from

Have a look at the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator).

```
printf("Hello ")
```

is evaluated at first, but its results are discarded.

```
printf("World!\n")
```

is evaluated next, and its return value decides the return value of the whole expression

```
(printf("Hello "), printf("World!\n"));
```

Meanwhile, you can see "Hello World!" printed to the console which could have been done in a less complicated way:

```
printf("Hello World!\n");
```

> does this have a special name

I would call it *grouping statements* using the comma operator.

> are there wanted side-effects

It can be useful when you want to create sequence points.

> is this actually used

For example, if you try

```
int success = (printf("Hello "), printf("World!\n"));
```

You can't really know the success of the first `printf`. This is a bad example of using the comma operator in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

> Comma operator:([Comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator))

*The comma operator expression has the form*

*lhs , rhs*
*where*

*lhs    -   any expression*
*rhs    -   any expression other than another comma operator (in other words, comma operator's associativity is left-to-right)*
*First, the left operand, lhs, is evaluated and its result value is discarded.*

*Then, a sequence point takes place, so that all side effects of lhs are complete.*

*Then, the right operand, rhs, is evaluated and its result is returned by the comma operator as a non-lvalue.*

> Code 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;

    n= (printf("Hello"),printf(", World!"));

    printf("\nn = %d",n);

    return 0;
}
```

Here the return value of prints will be `n=(5,8);` So the comma operator discards 5 and 8 will be assigned to n.

> code 2(without parentheses):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n;

    n= printf("Hello"),printf(", World!");

    printf("\nn = %d",n);

    return 0;
}
```

Here the first `n =5,8` will be assigned to 5 due to assignment operator has higher precedence than comma and right printf return will be discarded

> if you want to get both printf return value

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int n,m;

    n= printf("Hello"),m=printf(", World!");

    printf("\nn = %d,m = %d",n,m);

    return 0;
}
```

Here `n=5,m=8;`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> "*I wonder whether it is equivalent to just running them normally...*"

Since there is a [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between both comma-separated sub-expressions and comma-separated expressions are evaluated from left to right, this method shall not have a significant difference to the separate statement one (when used as in your example).

> 6.5.17 Comma operator
>
> 2 The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.
>
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (C11)

---

> Annex C
>
> 1 The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3:
>
> ...
>
> Between the evaluations of the first and second operands of the following operators: logical AND && (6.5.13); logical OR || (6.5.14); comma , (6.5.17).
>
> Source: ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (C11), Annex C

---

The assembly code is also equivalent for both methods:

Comma-separated subexpressions:

```
puts@plt:
 jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2fe2] # 404018 <puts@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 push 0x0
 jmp 401020 <.plt>
printf@plt:
 jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2fda] # 404020 <printf@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 push 0x1
 jmp 401020 <.plt>
_dl_relocate_static_pie:
 repz ret 
 nop WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
 nop DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
main:
 push rbp
 mov rbp,rsp
 sub rsp,0x10
 mov DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
 mov QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
 mov edi,0x402004
 mov eax,0x0
 call 401040 <printf@plt>
 mov edi,0x40200b
 call 401030 <puts@plt>
 mov eax,0x0
 leave 
 ret 
 nop WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
 nop DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (printf("Hello "), printf("World!\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

---

Separate statements:

```
puts@plt:
 jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2fe2] # 404018 <puts@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 push 0x0
 jmp 401020 <.plt>
printf@plt:
 jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0x2fda] # 404020 <printf@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 push 0x1
 jmp 401020 <.plt>
_dl_relocate_static_pie:
 repz ret 
 nop WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
 nop DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
main:
 push rbp
 mov rbp,rsp
 sub rsp,0x10
 mov DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],edi
 mov QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
 mov edi,0x402004
 mov eax,0x0
 call 401040 <printf@plt>
 mov edi,0x40200b
 call 401030 <puts@plt>
 mov eax,0x0
 leave 
 ret 
 nop WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
 nop DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Hello ");
    printf("World!\n");

    return 0;
}
```